# Setup .htaccess file for multiple React sites on the same domain

Tags: reactjs, .htaccess, react-router

I am trying to modify my .htaccess file to run two different React websites at the same time, but they are both on the **same domain**.

Let's say I am serving `/www`. I want:

```
domain.com/website1 to load /www/website1/index.html
```

and

```
domain.com/website2 to load /www/website2/index.html
```

They are React sites using `react-router`, so I need every URL to forward to the respective `index.html` file for routing to work properly. For example, `/www/website1/foo/bar` should forward to `/www/website1/index.html`.

I am having trouble finding examples since I am not forwarding based on the domain.

My .htaccess file currently looks like this, which works for React sites because it forwards everything to `/index.html`:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.html [L]
```

Comment: Write your above rule in two different htaccess located in website1 and website2 directory it should work as default.

Comment: That is a great recommendation that also gives me a new way to approach the issue. It didn't solve it though. The "above rule" causes it to load the index.html file but it still 404s on the CSS and JS because they are still pointed to `domain.com/static/bundle.js` not `domain.com/website1/static/bundle.js`

Comment: Use base href in your index.html with new url for this.